# How to prohibit a Python module from calling other modules?

Tags: python, security

In my Python application, I'll call 3rd party's Python modules. But these modules must have some restrictions for security problems. For example, they can't call some low level IO functions. Can I have a way to prohibit these 3rd party's modules from calling specific functions(modules)?

In my understanding, I can use two ways:

1. Check 3rd party's code statically before we use it. It's very hard to do it. Of course I can use some code to do it automatically, but it's not safe because some people can use some tricks to avoid it.
2. Do some configurations, so that the errors will be raised if 3rd party's code do some illegal operations. How can I do it correctly? I can't simply remove some modules, because some files can import them while some can't.

Are there any better ideas to do it?

Comment: http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython has some more ideas for you, but no concrete answer that I could find.

Answer (score 1):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython

Comment: It's very useful. Thank you! How about the performance for RestrictedPython?